# Ionic Cordova BuildConfig is defined multiple times

Tags: cordova, build.gradle, ionic5

I have an Ionic 5 project with a Cordova configuration. I built the Android APK in debug mode successfully in Android Studio. But whenever I started building the APK in release mode. It shows the following errors.

```
Type com.myapp.ionic.BuildConfig is defined multiple times: 
/myapp/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/project_dex_archive/release/out/com/myapp/ionic/BuildConfig.dex, 
/myapp/platforms/android/CordovaLib/build/.transforms/7d3c36a4bcd1f245fad4d095e288fc63/transformed/classes/classes_dex/classes.dex
```

Here is my **android/build.gradle** file:

```js
buildscript {
    apply from: 'CordovaLib/cordova.gradle'
    apply from: 'repositories.gradle'

    repositories repos

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.1'
    }

    cdvHelpers.verifyCordovaConfigForBuild()
}

allprojects {
    def hasRepositoriesGradle = file('repositories.gradle').exists()
    if (hasRepositoriesGradle) {
        apply from: 'repositories.gradle'
    } else {
        apply from: "${project.rootDir}/repositories.gradle"
    }

    repositories repos
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

project.ext {
    excludeAppGlideModule = true
}
```

and here is my **android/app/build.gradle** file,

```js
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

if (cordovaConfig.IS_GRADLE_PLUGIN_KOTLIN_ENABLED) {
    apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
    apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
}

buildscript {
    apply from: '../CordovaLib/cordova.gradle'

    if(cordovaConfig.IS_GRADLE_PLUGIN_KOTLIN_ENABLED) {
        if(!cdvHelpers.isVersionValid(cordovaConfig.KOTLIN_VERSION)) {
            throw new GradleException("The defined Kotlin version (${cordovaConfig.KOTLIN_VERSION}) does not appear to be a valid version.")
        }
    }

    apply from: 'repositories.gradle'
    repositories repos

    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.1"

        if (cordovaConfig.IS_GRADLE_PLUGIN_KOTLIN_ENABLED) {
            classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:${cordovaConfig.KOTLIN_VERSION}"
        }

        if(cordovaConfig.IS_GRADLE_PLUGIN_GOOGLE_SERVICES_ENABLED) {
            if(!cdvHelpers.isVersionValid(cordovaConfig.GRADLE_PLUGIN_GOOGLE_SERVICES_VERSION)) {
                throw new GradleException("The defined Google Services plugin version (4.3.14) does not appear to be a valid version.")
            }

            String gradlePluginGoogleServicesClassPath = "com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14"
            println "Adding classpath: ${gradlePluginGoogleServicesClassPath}"
            classpath gradlePluginGoogleServicesClassPath
        }
    }
}

allprojects {
    def hasRepositoriesGradle = file('repositories.gradle').exists()
    if (hasRepositoriesGradle) {
        apply from: 'repositories.gradle'
    } else {
        apply from: "${project.rootDir}/repositories.gradle"
    }

    repositories repos
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = cordovaConfig.GRADLE_VERSION
}

ext {
    apply from: '../CordovaLib/cordova.gradle'

    // Sets the versionCode to the given value.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvVersionCode')) {
        cdvVersionCode = null
    }
    // Whether to build architecture-specific APKs.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvBuildMultipleApks')) {
        cdvBuildMultipleApks = null
    }
    // Whether to append a 0 "abi digit" to versionCode when only a single APK is build
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvVersionCodeForceAbiDigit')) {
        cdvVersionCodeForceAbiDigit = null
    }
    // .properties files to use for release signing.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile')) {
        cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile = null
    }
    // .properties files to use for debug signing.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile')) {
        cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile = null
    }
    // Set by build.js script.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvBuildArch')) {
        cdvBuildArch = null
    }

    // Plugin gradle extensions can append to this to have code run at the end.
    cdvPluginPostBuildExtras = []
}

apply from: "../cordova-plugin-firebasex/ionic-build.gradle"
apply from: "../phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner/ionic-barcodescanner.gradle"

def hasBuildExtras1 = file('build-extras.gradle').exists()
if (hasBuildExtras1) {
    apply from: 'build-extras.gradle'
}

def hasBuildExtras2 = file('../build-extras.gradle').exists()
if (hasBuildExtras2) {
    apply from: '../build-extras.gradle'
}

privateHelpers.applyCordovaConfigCustomization()

if (ext.cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile == null && file('../debug-signing.properties').exists()) {
    ext.cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile = '../debug-signing.properties'
}
if (ext.cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile == null && file('../release-signing.properties').exists()) {
    ext.cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile = '../release-signing.properties'
}

ext.cdvBuildMultipleApks = cdvBuildMultipleApks == null ? false : cdvBuildMultipleApks.toBoolean();
ext.cdvVersionCodeForceAbiDigit = cdvVersionCodeForceAbiDigit == null ? false : cdvVersionCodeForceAbiDigit.toBoolean();
ext.cdvVersionCode = cdvVersionCode == null ? null : Integer.parseInt('' + cdvVersionCode)

def computeBuildTargetName(debugBuild) {
    def ret = 'assemble'
    if (cdvBuildMultipleApks && cdvBuildArch) {
        def arch = cdvBuildArch == 'arm' ? 'armv7' : cdvBuildArch
        ret += '' + arch.toUpperCase().charAt(0) + arch.substring(1);
    }
    return ret + (debugBuild ? 'Debug' : 'Release')
}

task cdvBuildDebug
cdvBuildDebug.dependsOn {
    return computeBuildTargetName(true)
}

task cdvBuildRelease
cdvBuildRelease.dependsOn {
    return computeBuildTargetName(false)
}

task cdvPrintProps {
    doLast {
        println('cdvBuildToolsVersion=' + cdvBuildToolsVersion)
        println('cdvVersionCode=' + cdvVersionCode)
        println('cdvVersionCodeForceAbiDigit=' + cdvVersionCodeForceAbiDigit)
        println('cdvSdkVersion=' + cdvSdkVersion)
        println('cdvMinSdkVersion=' + cdvMinSdkVersion)
        println('cdvMaxSdkVersion=' + cdvMaxSdkVersion)
        println('cdvBuildMultipleApks=' + cdvBuildMultipleApks)
        println('cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile=' + cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile)
        println('cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile=' + cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile)
        println('cdvBuildArch=' + cdvBuildArch)
        println('computedVersionCode=' + android.defaultConfig.versionCode)
        println('cdvAndroidXAppCompatVersion=' + cdvAndroidXAppCompatVersion)
        println('cdvAndroidXWebKitVersion=' + cdvAndroidXWebKitVersion)
        android.productFlavors.each { flavor ->
            println('computed' + flavor.name.capitalize() + 'VersionCode=' + flavor.versionCode)
        }
    }
}

android {
    namespace "com.myapp.ionic"
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += ['META-INF/NOTICE', 'META-INF/LICENSE']
        }
    }
    defaultConfig {
        versionCode cdvVersionCode ?: new BigInteger("" + privateHelpers.extractIntFromManifest("versionCode"))
        applicationId privateHelpers.extractStringFromManifest("package")

        minSdkVersion cordovaConfig.MIN_SDK_VERSION
        if (cordovaConfig.MAX_SDK_VERSION != null) {
            maxSdkVersion cordovaConfig.MAX_SDK_VERSION
        }
        targetSdkVersion cordovaConfig.SDK_VERSION
        compileSdkVersion cordovaConfig.COMPILE_SDK_VERSION
    }


    buildToolsVersion cordovaConfig.BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION

    if (Boolean.valueOf(cdvBuildMultipleApks)) {
        flavorDimensions "default"

        productFlavors {
            armeabi {
                versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode*10 + 1
                ndk {
                    abiFilters = ["armeabi"]
                }
            }
            armv7 {
                versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode*10 + 2
                ndk {
                    abiFilters = ["armeabi-v7a"]
                }
            }
            arm64 {
                versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode*10 + 3
                ndk {
                    abiFilters = ["arm64-v8a"]
                }
            }
            x86 {
                versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode*10 + 4
                ndk {
                    abiFilters = ["x86"]
                }
            }
            x86_64 {
                versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode*10 + 5
                ndk {
                    abiFilters = ["x86_64"]
                }
            }
        }
    } else if (Boolean.valueOf(cdvVersionCodeForceAbiDigit)) {
        defaultConfig {
            versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode*10
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    if (cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile) {
        signingConfigs {
            release {
                // These must be set or Gradle will complain (even if they are overridden).
                keyAlias = ""
                keyPassword = ""
                storeFile = null
                storePassword = ""
            }
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            }
        }
        addSigningProps(cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile, signingConfigs.release)
    }

    if (cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile) {
        addSigningProps(cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile, signingConfigs.debug)
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }
    
    lint {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

/*
 * WARNING: Cordova Lib and platform scripts do management inside of this code here,
 * if you are adding the dependencies manually, do so outside the comments, otherwise
 * the Cordova tools will overwrite them
 */


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:${cordovaConfig.ANDROIDX_APP_COMPAT_VERSION}"
    implementation "androidx.core:core-splashscreen:${cordovaConfig.ANDROIDX_CORE_SPLASHSCREEN_VERSION}"

    if (cordovaConfig.IS_GRADLE_PLUGIN_KOTLIN_ENABLED) {
        implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:${cordovaConfig.KOTLIN_VERSION}"
    }

    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES START
    implementation(project(path: ":CordovaLib"))
    implementation "androidx.webkit:webkit:1.4.0"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:18.0.2"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.4.0"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:21.2.0"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.1.0"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-config:21.2.0"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:20.3.0"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.1.0"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging:20.2.0"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display:20.2.0"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:24.4.1"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-functions:20.2.1"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:21.1.0"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-installations:17.1.0"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:18.3.2"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-ndk:18.3.2"
    implementation "com.google.code.gson:gson:2.9.0"
    implementation "io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:1.46.0"
    implementation "androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0"
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1"
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES END
}

def addSigningProps(propsFilePath, signingConfig) {
    def propsFile = file(propsFilePath)
    def props = new Properties()
    propsFile.withReader { reader ->
        props.load(reader)
    }

    def storeFile = new File(props.get('key.store') ?: privateHelpers.ensureValueExists(propsFilePath, props, 'storeFile'))
    if (!storeFile.isAbsolute()) {
        storeFile = RelativePath.parse(true, storeFile.toString()).getFile(propsFile.getParentFile())
    }
    if (!storeFile.exists()) {
        throw new FileNotFoundException('Keystore file does not exist: ' + storeFile.getAbsolutePath())
    }
    signingConfig.keyAlias = props.get('key.alias') ?: privateHelpers.ensureValueExists(propsFilePath, props, 'keyAlias')
    signingConfig.keyPassword = props.get('keyPassword', props.get('key.alias.password', signingConfig.keyPassword))
    signingConfig.storeFile = storeFile
    signingConfig.storePassword = props.get('storePassword', props.get('key.store.password', signingConfig.storePassword))
    def storeType = props.get('storeType', props.get('key.store.type', ''))
    if (!storeType) {
        def filename = storeFile.getName().toLowerCase()
        if (filename.endsWith('.p12') || filename.endsWith('.pfx')) {
            storeType = 'pkcs12'
        } else {
            storeType = signingConfig.storeType // "jks"
        }
    }
    signingConfig.storeType = storeType
}

for (def func : cdvPluginPostBuildExtras) {
    func()
}

if (hasProperty('postBuildExtras')) {
    postBuildExtras()
}

if (cordovaConfig.IS_GRADLE_PLUGIN_GOOGLE_SERVICES_ENABLED) {
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}
```

How to fix the above issue?